# Apache XML Security with Quarkus Native

Tags: java, xml, quarkus, graalvm

I'm using Apache XML Security sign some XML Messages and would like to package my service as a native image.

I've enabled `-Dquarkus.native.enable-all-security-services=true` and `-Dquarkus.ssl.native=true` but when I call `org.apache.xml.security.Init.init()` in the native image.

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1593)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1556)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:932)
    at org.apache.xml.security.utils.I18n.init(I18n.java:157)
    at org.apache.xml.security.Init.dynamicInit(Init.java:114)
    at org.apache.xml.security.Init.init(Init.java:92)
```

It seems to be trying to load some sort of Locale file at runtime, is it possible to get this working?

Comment: Do you have this issue only in native mode?, Have you tried as well in JVM mode?, are you using directly the apache xml security dependency or this one https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/reference/extensions/xmlsecurity.html ?

Comment: I’m using it directly, it works fine in jvm mode.

Comment: It could be the docker container I’m running it in? But I’m using the standard quarkus container.

Comment: I've been checking I think that the issue is some incompatibility with graalvm, I would suggest you to try the dependency from quarkus, It might contain the api that you requires. Quarkus does some trinkering optimizing you code and dependencies, but your app works fine in JVM mode so I think that this might be some issue with the classloading or if the library uses reflection with that. Graalvm is not compatbile by default with all libraries.

Comment: This looks promising: https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/blob/main/extensions/xmlsecurity/deployment/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/quarkus/component/xmlsecurity/deployment/XmlsecurityProcessor.java